# Installed another Rails application on server and existing application stop working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I got below error when install another `rails application` on server.

```
App 970 stderr: Cannot execute "/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent": Permission denied (errno=13)
[ 2017-04-19 14:25:36.2735 898/7f6d6a5e4700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/html/entertainoz: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: 7312b405
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-S9HJRx.html
  Message from application: Cannot execute "/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/support-binaries/PassengerAgent": Permission denied (errno=13)
```

I tried to find the issue but still not get it.

Comment: You may want to look into the cause of your Permission Denied (13) on the top line.

Also check the contents of `/tmp/passenger-error-S9HJRx.html` which may tell you more.

This question will be unanswerable as there is not enough info here.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.